# Determine $(n-1)$ eigenvectors of $f$ associated to $0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&\cdots&1\\1&1&\cdots&1\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&1\\1&1&\cdots&1\end{pmatrix}\in\mathcal M_n(\mathbb R).$$
>
> 1. Prove that $0$ and $n$ are eigenvalue of $A$.
> 2. Determine the characteristic polynomial. (Hint: You can use the basis $(e_1, e_2 - e_1, \cdots, e_n - e_1)$)
> 3. Determine the eigenvalues of $A$.
> 4. Prove that $f(e_1)$ is an eigenvector.
> 5. Determine $(n-1)$ eigenvectors of $f$ associated to $0$.
> 6. Prove that there exists a basis $\mathcal{B_2}$ in which the matrix is of the form:
>    $$D = \begin{pmatrix}
>    n & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
>    0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
>    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
>    0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
>    \end{pmatrix}$$

---

1. Taking the vector $ v = 
   \begin{pmatrix}
   1 \\
   1 \\
   \vdots \\
   1 
   \end{pmatrix}$

We get: $Av = nv$.

But I could not see how $0$ can be an eigenvalue.

2. $$P_A(X) = \begin{vmatrix}
   1 - X & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
   1 & 1 - X & \cdots & 1 \\ 
   \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & 1 \\
   1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 - X
   \end{vmatrix}
   =
   (1 - X)\begin{vmatrix}
   1  & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
   1 & 1 - X & \cdots & 1 \\ 
   \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & 1 \\
   1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 - X
   \end{vmatrix}$$

I could not proceed to get an expression of $P_f(X)$ as I could not see how to use the hint.

4. Computing $ Ae_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
   1 \\
   1 \\
   \vdots \\
   1 
   \end{pmatrix}$ which is not related to the eigenvalues $0$ or $n$.
5. I am stuck in this question too.

Comment: Write the matrix $A$ in the basis from part (2) (the only difficult part is the first column). This will make the problem much easier.

Comment: @hunter I couldn't get the change of basis matrix. Can you elaborate more please? Thank you.

Comment: The image of $A$ is obviously one-dimensional. What is the nullity of this matrix and how does that relate to its eigenvalues?

Comment: First of all the rank of $A$ is $1$, so it is not invertible and so $0$ is an eigenvalues of $A$. 

 By dimension theorem, null space of $A$ has dimention $n-1$ which is same as the eigen space corresponding to $0$, so $0$ is an eigenvalue with multipilicity $n-1$ and hence the other eigenvalue must the trace $n$ of $A$.
Hence $$\sigma(A)=\{0,n\}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1)$ For $\lambda=0$, try $v=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\\vdots\\1\\1-n\end{pmatrix}$.

$(2)$ For instance,  use the change of basis matrix (whose columns are the $-e_1+e_i$).

$(4)$  $f(e_1)$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $n$.

$(5)$  Take the eigenvector in $(1)$ and move the $1-n$ around to different coordinates, i.e. put $1-n$ in the $i$th coordinate,  and $1$'s everywhere else.  $n-1$ of these are linearly independent.

$(6)$  Since it has a $n-1$ linearly independent eigenvectors for $\lambda =0$, and $1$ for $\lambda =n$, there is such a basis (consisting of eigenvectors) .

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_1 = e_1$, $f_2 = e_2 - e_1$, ..., $f_n = e_n - e_1$ as in the hint. Note that $\sum f_i = (\sum e_i) - (n-1) e_1$.

Then $A$ annihilates $f_2$, $f_3$, ..., and $f_n$. Meanwhile, 
\begin{align*}
Af_1 &= \sum_i {e_i} \\
&= \sum_i f_i + (n-1)  e_1 \\
&= nf_1 + \sum_{i \neq 1} f_i, 
\end{align*}
so the matrix for $A$ in the new basis is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
n & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$